# Xamarin Forms: How to combine values from different get web service using Binding to ListView

Tags: xamarin.forms

Dears,

I am calling two web service in my xamarin forms project. From the first web service I am getting the root URL of an image and from the second I am getting the remaining url part.  Only the second web service response is connected with the listview using ItemsSource property. My root url is **d1kv7s9g8y3npv.cloudfront.net**. Currently, I hardcoded the rooturl value in my code.

My Image code:

```
                       <Image 
                            Source="{Binding remainingUrl , StringFormat='d1kv7s9g8y3npv.cloudfront.net{0:F0}'}"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            WidthRequest="50" />
```

So how can I add the root url to this image code without hardcoding?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not to make a property which will combine both of the URL parts and simply bind to it?

Comment: You mean like this: public string FirstLastName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, solve the issue using the Ivalueconverter.
The mainurl is stored in a variable using Application.Current.Properties.

The second web service is a list of items. So I need to join the two url and show it in the UI. For this, I am using IValueConverter.

My converter code:

```
public class UrlsLinkconverter : IValueConverter
{
#region IValueConverter implementation
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return string.Empty;

    string rootUrl = Application.Current.Properties["rootUrl"].ToString();
    string fullUrl = String.Concat("http://" + rootUrl,value.ToString())
    Debug.WriteLine("fullUrl::>>>>"+fullUrl);
    return fullUrl.ToString();
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple solution to your problem.
Simply create a property which will combine the both parts of the URL:

```
// In your ViewModel
public string CombinedUrl => $"{firstPart}/{secondPart}";

// In your XAML
<Image 
   Source="{Binding CombinedUrl}"
   HorizontalOptions="Start"
   VerticalOptions="Start"
   WidthRequest="50" />
```

Please pay attention to naming conventions, from your example I can see that you are using a lowercase name 'remainingUrl' for a property which violates the [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).

Comment: public string CombinedUrl => $"{firstPart}/{secondPart}";
need to add this code in the model class, right?

Comment: I updated my answer, hope that now it will be easier to understand what I meant.

Comment: I am not using viewmodel class. Is it possible to apply this in model or xaml.cs class?

Comment: If you are binding to your model or xaml.cs and it is working then - yes, however you should bind to a ViewModel if you want to follow MVVM.